# View does not get updated on Mobile app after angular variables are updated, though it works on browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mobile, angular8

When the angular variables are updated inside the component after some API calls, it should be reflected in the UI of the mobile view (depending on the value of *ngIf), but it does not. It works on the web, desktop, etc.
And if I create an extra button on the mobile page and click it OR reload the page, it works in mobile too. It seems like the mobile page requires initial interaction, to load the page correctly according to the variable change. It does not do the work itself.

```
<div *ngIf="!hasToken">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Login()"><img src="images/icon-ms.ico">Login</button>
</div>
```

AngularComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.exampleService.getData(id).subscribe((result) => {
  if (result != undefined || result != null) {
  this.hasToken= true;
 }
}
```

Once the variable `hasToken` becomes **true** on ngOnInit(), it should hide the **Login** button, but it does not, though the value of the variable gets updated.

Any suggestion to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by mobile? What kind of application is it? NativeScript? Ionic? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you're experiencing is related to change detection.
I suggest avoiding manually subscribing in the controller by using the async pipe. This improves the performance and works great with change detection.

You can do something like this:

```js
readonly hasToken$ = this.exampleService.getData(id).pipe(map(result => !!result));
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(hasToken$ | async) === false">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Login()"><img src="images/icon-ms.ico">Login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also to hack this, I added a false window click event to trigger the page for initial interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you init/update your variable is incorrect. Can you add your .ts?
You can also check [ChangeDetectorRef.MarkForCheck()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and [ngOnchanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) but it's way too overkill for your problem.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with ts script. I also tried by keeping this.ref.markForCheck(); and this.ref.detectChanges(); It still does not work. I tried calling this just after hasToken variable.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check if "result != undefined || result != null" is true? Did you try to console.log something after this.hasToken= true;

Btw, your condition isn't good ... if result === undefined so result !== null so the result is true and vice versa.
You should just test it like it :
if (result) {}